# Cassandra cpp driver on Windows/RHEL

Tags: cassandra, clang

I am trying to build cassandra cpp driver on rhel 6.4.So the requirement is to make this work on windows/RHEL with Visual Studio/gcc compiler.So what it takes to make this driver work on RHEL/windows without any additional packaging being required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CentOS 6.4 (minimal)

**1. Get the dependencies**

```
sudo yum install gcc-c++ glibc glibc-devel boost boost-devel openssl openssl-devel libssh2 libssh2-devel zlib zlib-devel make cmake git
```

**2. Clone the C++ driver for Cassandra from its repository**

```
git clone https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver.git
```

**3. Build**

```
cd cpp-driver
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
make
```

That's it. Most likely, the driver will be packaged sooner or later and building it will not be necessary (unless you want to hack with the dev version).

## Windows

**1. Get the dependencies**

Install [Zlib](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm), [OpenSSL](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm), [libSSH2](http://www.libssh2.org/download/), [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary) and [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html) (in this order). LibSSH2 and Boost must be compiled with Visual Studio (these processes are beyond the scope of this answer, but usually go off smoothly). Remeber the directories where you put them.

**2. Download the C++ driver for Cassandra**

You can clone the repository (if you have Git client at hand) or download the [zipped source](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/archive/master.zip).

**3. Configure and build**

Run CMake GUI, select your toolchain, and point to the cpp-driver directory ('Where is the source code'). Hit 'Configure'. You will see some red entries that need to be set manually. Most likely these are locations of the freshly installed libraries. Set them and 'Configure' until no more red fields are present. Then hit 'Generate' and you will get an MSVS solution ready to be imported and built.

## Caveats

At the time of this writing the C++ driver for Cassandra undergoes intense development. Therefore, the process described above may require appropriate tuning.

Another thing worth remembering is that (at the time of this writing) the C++ driver has only C++ interface. To preserve ABI compatibility it is advised to stick to **one toolchain** when **building** and **using** the driver.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and sorry for not putting it properly. So the requirement is to make this work on windows/RHEL with Visual Studio/gcc compiler. So can you guide me on this? About libc++ as mentioned in this link http://libcxx.llvm.org/ implementation is in progress. SO what it takes to make this driver work on windows/RHEL without any additional packaging being required?

Comment: Any Suggestions?? I will try if you can give me some pointers :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It was a great help. I followed all steps for windows and tried compiling. But unfortunately i am getting lot of linker errors like error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_free  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_free error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)  I tried differenrt options but no success:( Can you help? Also are insert operations on cassandra supported by the driver currently?

Comment: @user3201592 Sure, INSERTs do work. Regarding the link errors: you might have mixed 32/64-bit binaries; try sticking to 32-bit. Never tried 64-bit, but it should also work. If this doesn't help I would suggest you to open a new question and dump all info there (i.e. how did you build boost, linker commandline, CMakeCache.txt, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Nerdosclerosis .I am setting up new win32 machine and will be trying out this. Will keep you posted on this...